# mixin templates: how to halt compilation?

Tags: templates, d

I have a mixin template which is only valid with certain arguments. I want to halt the compilation with an error message if the arguments are invalid. For templates I'd use `assert(false, "Invalid args for Yoo")` but this does not work for mixin templates. How to halt compilation for the example below?

```d
mixin template Yoo(args...) {
  static if (args.length == 0) {
    pragma(msg, "Invalid args! (how to halt the compilation?)");
  } else {
    pragma(msg, "Valid args:", args);
  }
}

void main() {
  mixin Yoo;
  mixin Yoo!(1,2,3);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do

```d
static assert(0, "Invalid args!");
```

instead of the pragma msg. Static assert is like `assert`, just compile time and it will not get removed in release mode because its only checked while compiling and not included in the compiled code.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to `static assert` is a template constraint:

```d
mixin template Yoo(args...) if (args.length > 0) {
```

With the above, `Yoo!()` will fail to compile with a message like

> Error: mixin d.Yoo!() does not match template declaration Yoo(args...) if (args.length > 0)

The advantage of this is that, if somebody else wanted, they could define their
own `Yoo` that *does* accept no args. With a `static assert` and no template
constraints, their definition would conflict.

However, `static assert` does allow you to provide a more helpful message.